# Missing the leading 0(s) in PHP string using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, string

I have a PHP `fileName` variable which I am trying to pass to another `test.php` file using Ajax. Let's say the `test` file simply echoes the PHP variable passed to it. This is the piece of code which is causing problems for me:

```
like.php:

        $(".samp").on("click", ".like", function(){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "test.php",
               data: {favorite : '.$fileName.'},
               success: function(data) {
                   $("p.disp").text(data);
                    $("#liker").attr("class","unlike");
                    $("#icon").attr("class","fa fa-heart fa-lg");
               }
           });
        });


test.php:
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['favorite']))
      {
        $fileName = $_POST['favorite'];
        echo $fileName;
      }
?>
```

In my PHP program, I found the `gettype($fileName)` to be string and echoed it as '01923' before my Ajax call. But after the Ajax call, from the echo statement in `test.php`, the string displayed is '1923'. Why am I losing the leading 0? I checked the `gettype($_POST['favorite'])` to be string in the `test.php` as well. But somehow it's losing a 0 when it is passed to the `test.php`. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

P.S- I want to keep the string as it is. I do not want append 0s to it in the `test.php` as I do not know the number of leading zeroes for each `fileName`.

Comment: What are the dots in `favorite : '.$fileName.'`?

Comment: I'm guessing you're echoing this JS code from PHP, hence the `'` are delimiting the PHP, not the JS, hence the value is being interpreted as a integer, not a string, and therefore the leading zeroes are removed. You need another set of quotes around the value for JS to use.

Comment: I assume the dots are php's string concatenation operator, and Ashwin has not shown the surrounding php around this javascript snippet. It's probably full of `<?php echo "..."?>`

Comment: @u_molder: Yes, Joe is right. I am using it as a concatenation operator. I will include some php code surrounding this, so it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always look at your rendered result when generating HTML (and, in this case, JavaScript) using PHP.

Here, you should see you end up with:

```
// ...
data: {favorite: 01923},
// ...
```

Which, I hope you can clearly see, is numeric and will therefore be trimmed to `1923`.

When you want to inject a value from PHP into JavaScript, you should use `json_encode`. Specifically...

```
data: {favorite: '.json_encode($fileName).'}
```

This will also take care of anything that may have been an injection vulnerability before, giving you a value that can be read reliably by JavaScript. This works with strings, numbers, booleans, even arrays and objects (with some fiddling about)

Answer (score 3):

With php, it is better to close the php tag and open a new one when outputting html, javascript, and css, etc.

Do like this:

```
<?php
  $somephpcode = do_things();
?>
<p> Now we output html </p>
<script>
  // Now we output javascript
  // and do some ajax with interpolation like:
  // data: {favorite : "<?php echo $fileName;?>"}
</script>
```

And not like this:

```
<?php
  $somephpcode = do_things();
  echo '<p> Now we output html </p>
  <script>
    // Now we output javascript
    // and do some ajax with interpolation like:
    // data: {favorite : '.$fileName.'}
  </script>';
?>
```

With the latter case, you would have to wrap *another* set of quotes around the outputted string, and this can be confusing.

Comment: Thank you. But I am working with a large code base, which is unfortunately formatted this way and so this isn't possible for me to change throughout. But, will remember this tip for my work in future.

Comment: That is very unfortunate. You will encounter this problem many times in the future. This code structure is a kind of debt.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

`data: {favorite : '.$fileName.'},`

with this:

`data: {favorite : "'.$fileName.'"},`

Note the double quotes before and after the file name.

The problem is that without the quotes, the code generates this:

`data: {favorite : 01923},`

which is interpreted as an integer and thus the `0` is lost.

When using quotes, the output is:

`data: {favorite : "01923"},`

which is treated as a string and the `0` will not be lost.

Comment: It is better to reformat the surrounding code (to solve the root problem) than hastily patch the quotes (to cover up the symptom)

Comment: @jotaelesalinas: This solved my problem, thanks. But like Joe said, was a quick fix..so, just upvoted this and choosing the other answer as the correct one.

Comment: Definitely, @JoeFrambach. I just wanted to let Ashwin know why the code was not working. Having said that, I also prefer your answer :)